# How to disable auto-generation of default fields in ElasticSearch Query with TermsAggregationBuilder and QueryBuilders

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am migrating from ElasticSearch v1.0.0 to v7.13.1. I know that support for Type specification has been removed by ElasticSearch version beyond 7.0.0.
Also, there are certain improvements done by the ElasticSearch in terms of classes such as TermsAggregationBuilder replaces TermsBuilder.

But when I am preparing queries using QueryBuilders and AggregationBuilder, I could see some extra fields generated, that I don't want.

Is there any way to avoid them programmatically?

**Before**

```
private TermsBuilder createAggreationsUriDetails() {
        return AggregationBuilders
                .terms(xxxxxxxx)...
```

**After**

```
private TermsAggregationBuilder createAggreationsUriDetails() {
        return AggregationBuilders
                .terms(ElasticConstants.URI)...
```

Also I am using matchQuery() to prepare match query with the upgraded ES version. Still I could see some extra fields. Same goes for Order as well.

Query comparison with old and new elasticsearch version

Before

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "uri.raw": {
              "query": "sample_uri",
              "type": "boolean"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "from": 1655145000000,
              "to": 1655231400000,
              "include_lower": "true",
              "include_upper": "false",
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "uri": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "uri.raw",
        "size": 1,
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "client_id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "client_id",
            "size": 10000,
            "order": {
              "_count": "desc"
            }
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "response_code": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "response_code.raw",
                "size": 8,
                "order": {
                  "_count": "desc"
                }
              },
              "aggregations": {
                "datetime": {
                  "date_histogram": {
                    "field": "@timestamp",
                    "interval": "1m",
                    "min_doc_count": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query developed with new ES version QueryBuilder

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "uri.raw": {
              "query": "sample_url",
              "operator": "OR",
              "prefix_length": 0,
              "max_expansions": 50,
              "fuzzy_transpositions": "true",
              "lenient": "false",
              "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
              "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": "true",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "from": 1655145000000,
              "to": 1655231400000,
              "include_lower": "true",
              "include_upper": "false",
              "format": "epoch_millis",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": "true",
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "uri": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "uri.raw",
        "size": 1,
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
        "show_term_doc_count_error": "false",
        "order": [
          {
            "_count": "desc"
          },
          {
            "_key": "asc"
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "client_id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "client_id",
            "size": 10000,
            "min_doc_count": 1,
            "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
            "show_term_doc_count_error": "false",
            "order": [
              {
                "_count": "desc"
              },
              {
                "_key": "asc"
              }
            ]
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "response_code": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "response_code.raw",
                "size": 8,
                "min_doc_count": 1,
                "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                "show_term_doc_count_error": "false",
                "order": [
                  {
                    "_count": "desc"
                  },
                  {
                    "_key": "asc"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "aggregations": {
                "datetime": {
                  "date_histogram": {
                    "field": "@timestamp",
                    "interval": "60000ms",
                    "offset": 0,
                    "order": {
                      "_key": "asc"
                    },
                    "keyed": "false",
                    "min_doc_count": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see as a extra fields are actually the params of the query for example `match` query in your 7.X looks like below:

```
"match": {
            "uri.raw": {
              "query": "sample_url",
              "operator": "OR",
              "prefix_length": 0,
              "max_expansions": 50,
              "fuzzy_transpositions": "true",
              "lenient": "false",
              "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
              "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": "true",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
```

These `operator`, `prefix_length`, `lenient` all are the params of `match` query and even if you don't provide it will be added with their default values, these will be added at Elasticsearch side when you hit the query in JSON format without these params, so don't worry about them, if you want you can change some of these params value to see the corresponding impact on your query results, like change `operator` to `AND` and number of search results for multi-terms will be less.

**Note: You can also check the code of [MatchQueryBuilder](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/MatchQueryBuilder.java) in the Elasticsearch code base to understand they are using the builder design pattern, and how they are passing the default values of the params.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Amit, But what about Order, Actually Previously I was using ".order(Terms.Order.count(false)" but as I could not see the same in newer versions, I am using '.order(BucketOrder.count(false))" . But I could see "_key" as well in my response along with "_count". Will this impact my application?

```
"order": [
          {
            "_count": "desc"
          },
          {
            "_key": "asc"
          }
        ]
```

Comment: @VishnuChaturvedi u mean that you don't want `_count` to come in your terms aggs?

Comment: Amit I want '_count' but I don't need '_key'

Comment: @VishnuChaturvedi, thats fine, it will impact your aggs result, you can just ignore it while parsing the response

Answer (score 1):

You can not disable that because it is default value generated by Elasticsearch.

Also, You are able to see as you are printing query in console but it is expected behaviour.

Below is simple match query with required params:

```json
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "message": {
        "query": "this is a test"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when you create above query using Java client and print in console it will look like below as it will print other default param value as well which is pass to Elasticsearch while query is executed.

```json
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "message": {
              "query": "this is a test",
              "operator": "OR",
              "prefix_length": 0,
              "max_expansions": 50,
              "fuzzy_transpositions": "true",
              "lenient": "false",
              "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
              "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": "true",
              "boost": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```